# How Git select the rebase starting point?

Tags: git, rebase

How does git rebase select a starting commit from the source (often feature) branch?

I am guessing  git goes back to the common ancestor of src and dst branch.

What if the two branches have no common commits?

Comment: It depends on the `refspec` of the parameters you pass to rebase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One useful thing to know—you may already know this—is that rebase works by *copying* commits.  It copies just the right commits, making the new copies go right after the end of the new base.

The selection of commits to rebase (to copy) actually uses one of the most crucial things to know about Git and its commit selection.  When you understand this, you will also understand how `git log` and `git rev-list` work.<sup>1</sup>

First, remember that Git's commits form a *graph* (specifically a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG, but you don't need to worry about that for a long time yet).  Each commit remembers its parent, or for a merge commit, all of its parents.  When there are no merge commits in the part of the graph we draw, we'll get a *tree* structure rather than an arbitrary DAG.  Rebase works best when you don't have merges, since rebase normally throws away merges anyway.

We can—and you should—draw these graphs.  You can get Git to do this for you, with `git log --graph` for instance.  It draws them vertically which takes too much room for our purposes here, so we'll draw them horizontally instead, with newer commits on the right and older ones on the left.

Here's an example graph:

```
...<- o <- o <- o <- o
            \
             o <- o <- o <- o
```

Each `o` represents some *commit* in the graph.  In formal graph theory each commit would be a *vertex* in the graph, but sometimes these are called *nodes* instead, and I tend to use the words "nodes" and "commit nodes" to describe them.

The "true name" of each commit node is a Git hash, one of those big ugly 40-character `a234567...` things.  Given a Git hash, Git can look up any object (including, of course, commits) in the repository.  But somehow we have to remember these "true names", which are entirely not-memorable.

Since each commit remembers its parent, though, we can start from any commit and work backwards in history (but not forwards!).  What we need is to remember the *most recent* or *tip-most* commit of a branch.  We get Git to do this for us, by having Git save the big ugly hash in a *branch name*, like `master` or `develop`.

You can use `git rev-parse` to turn such a name into a hash:

```
$ git rev-parse master
08bb3500a2a718c3c78b0547c68601cafa7a8fd9
```

This means that `master` points to the commit whose real name is `08bb350...`.  That commit has, inside it, the real name of a previous commit, and so on.

Let's draw that example graph again but add the branch names this time.  I'll make it more compact, too: we know commits always point "backwards" (to their parents) so there's no need to draw those in as arrows, we can just use connecting lines.  And I'm going to mark two of the commits with `*` this time:

```
...--*--*--o--o        <-- master
         \
          o--o--o--o   <-- develop
```

Note that the *name* `master` selects, specifically, the very *tip* of the `master` branch.  Likewise, the name `develop` selects just the tip of the `develop` branch.  But Git often doesn't just select *one* commit.  Often, when we tell Git to look at one commit in particular, we're really asking Git to consider that commit *and* all of its parents.

When we start from `master` and work backwards, we get the two commits that are exclusively on `master` (the tip, and the one before the tip) and then we get the second `*` commit, and the first `*`, and so on.

When we start from `develop` and work backwards, we get the four commits that are exclusively on `develop`, and then the second `*` commit, and then the first `*`, and so on.

That is, the two `*` commits are, in fact, on *both* branches.

Note that we can draw the graph like this just as easily:

```
          o--o          <-- master
         /
...--*--*--o--o--o--o   <-- develop
```

or like this:

```
          o--o        <-- master
         /
...--*--*
         \
          o--o--o--o   <-- develop
```

All these drawings represent the same graph, and there's nothing particularly special about `master`.

#### This is the heart of the problem that `rebase` must solve

If we want to rebase `develop` on `master`, `git rebase` must somehow pick the four commits that are *only* on `develop`, while excluding all the commits that are *also* on `master`.

This is where Git's `X..Y` syntax comes in.  Oddly, rebase doesn't use it!  There's a reason for that, but let's just look at the syntax for the moment.  With this syntax—in this case, with `master..develop`—we ask Git to start from a tip commit, the tip of `develop`, and select every commit going back in time, all the way to the beginning, that it can from there; but also start from the tip of `master`, and *un*-select every commit going back in time.

I like to think of this as temporarily painting commits green (go) and red (stop).  We can do the green paint first, painting the four `o`s on `develop` plus the two `*`s plus whatever comes before them, then put red paint on top starting from the two `o`s on master and continuing on to the two `*`s and everything that comes before those.  Or, we can do the red paint first, and then do the green paint but stop painting as soon as we find a red node.  Either way we'll wind up with just the four exclusive-to-`develop` commits "painted green".

This is how `git rebase` knows to copy those four commits, and not any other commits.

The place that `rebase` starts *from* is normally your current branch:

```
$ git branch
  diff-merge-base
  master
  precious
* stash-exp
```

(so in this case I'm currently on `stash-exp`).

The place that `rebase` copies *to*—or rather, "copies after"—comes from the argument to `git rebase`:

```
$ git rebase master
```

This, as it turns out, is *also* the place that `git rebase` gets its idea of "red commits" (what *not* to copy).

Rebase effectively takes your argument, such as `master`, and your current branch name—in my case, `stash-exp`, but let's say `develop`—and uses `git rev-list`<sup>2</sup> to get the IDs of the commits to copy:

```
$ git rev-list master..develop
```

(you have to run this *before* the rebase, of course).

#### Extra wrinkle #1

When you run `git rebase`, it tries to check to see if the *other* branch—the one you're rebasing onto—has copies of commits that you have.  That is, suppose we look at the version graph we drew like this:

```
          o--o
         /
...--*--*
         \
          o--o--o--o
```

In this graph, there are two forks from final common `*` commit.  We could easily rebase either one onto the other.  But what if one of the top-line `o` commits matches, more or less, one of the bottom-line `o` commits?  It would be nice to omit the extra.  Let's rebase the bottom line onto the top, but let's label these commits `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` and note, on the top, that one of the `o`s is Just Like `B`:

```
          o--B'
         /
...--*--*
         \
          A--B--C--D
```

(this is the kind of graph you get when you use `cherry-pick`, for instance).  Commits `B` and `B'` are basically copies of each other.  So when we rebase the lower four commits, we really should just copy `A`, `C`, and `D`, giving:

```
          o--B'
         /    \
...--*--*      A'-C'-D'
         \
          A--B--C--D
```

Last, let's put the labels back on.  We want `master` to point to `B'`, and `develop` to point to `D'`, like this:

```
          o--B'          <-- master
         /    \
...--*--*      A'-C'-D'  <-- develop
         \
          A--B--C--D     [abandoned]
```

What happens to the original `A--B--C--D` chain?  We've labeled it "abandoned" here, but in fact, Git hangs on to it for a while, using both the *reflog* mechanism—e.g., we can ask Git to find `develop@{1}` which finds the original commit `D`—and also the special name `ORIG_HEAD`, which `rebase` sets up to point to `D`.  The reflog entry sticks around for 30 days by default,<sup>3</sup> while the name `ORIG_HEAD` sticks around until something (usually another rebase) overwrites it.

#### Extra wrinkle #2

Sometimes, this bit of Git magic—use one name like `master` to "paint commits red", and then use the *same* name to decide where to put the copies—is insufficient.  For some cases, you need to tell `git rebase` to *stop* copying at some specific point, but to put the *new* copies somewhere else.  In this case, you can use `git rebase --onto`:

`git rebase --onto target upstream`

([the rebase documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) calls the red-paint "stop" argument *`upstream`*).  The default is that *`upstream`* is both the `--onto` target *and* the stop-copy red-paint indicator, and it works when the point to stop is in the right place in the history of the point to copy-onto.  That's usually true—and quite often (but not always), the thing to give as the *`upstream`* for some branch `foo` is an `origin/foo` remote-tracking branch that you will set<sup>4</sup> as the *upstream* for `foo`, which I think is why rebase calls this argument *`upstream`*.

#### What if the two branches have no common commits?

> What if the two branches have no common commits?

In this case, the "paint commit nodes red" step has no effect on the "paint commits green" step:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master

o--o--o      <-- unrelated
```

If you're on branch `unrelated` and you run `git rebase master`, Git effectively paints the three `unrelated`-branch commits green and the four `master`-branch commits red, then takes the green-painted commits, which are the three commits reachable from `unrelated`'s tip commit.  The rebase code then copies those commits:

```
o--o--o--o           <-- master
          \
           o--o--o   <-- unrelated

o--o--o              [abandoned]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, `git rev-list` has about a million flags, so this is a bit of an overstatement, since it won't help you so much with all the flags. :-)

<sup>2</sup>There are a number of side complications here: sometimes `git rebase` actually uses `git rev-list` directly, and sometimes it doesn't.  The effect is pretty much the same, though.

<sup>3</sup>This is configurable: `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` control the defaults, and there are additional names you can set for specific patterns.

<sup>4</sup>You can set this explicitly with `git branch --set-upstream-to`, but for these kinds of branches, it's generally set automatically when you use `git checkout` to create the branch initially.  Once it's set, `git rebase`, with no extra arguments, will find it automatically as well.

Comment: I was counting in my head: "Torek in 3...2...1" +1

Comment: "that rebase works by copying commits": I guess the more precise term would be "by cherry-picking commits".

Comment: @VonC: well, sometimes it uses `git chery-pick`, and sometimes it uses `git format-patch | git am`.  The effect is the same either way, and I like to *define* rebase in terms of cherry-pick.

Comment: For more on the revision graph and its revision spec (the dots syntax), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/850695/6309. "The revision spec contains a set of positive references (starting points) and negative references (stopping points) and additional filters (limit number of revisions, grep commit text etc). Git starts with the positive references and goes back through the revision history, stopping when it encounters revisions that are reachable from the negative references (not necessarily just when it reaches one of the negative references themselves)."

Comment: You touch on LCA on http://stackoverflow.com/a/36437843/6309, but without ever mentioning those positive and negative references. You did mention them in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38649887/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/34542654/6309 though. I like the graphic representation in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309.

Comment: @VonC: The Venn diagrams work for simpler cases; the red/green paint analogy allows for multiple positive and negative references, where it's harder to do the Venn diagrams.  Interestingly (and sometimes frustratingly) you cannot control the order of operations in Git (you can in Mercurial since it's just using Python sets underneath).  The general case for LCAs needs full DAG theory since there can be multiple "lowest" common ancestors.  So for this particular answer, with `rebase`'s limited use of the operators, I left a lot out. :-)

Comment: I agree. No need for LCA here. I just wanted to link a bunch of other interesting answers to this one :)

Comment: Torek - thank you. The level of detail is overwhelming and I am sure many will find the post useful. For my purposes how git does rebase is less important. It's interesting from academic and internal to git code reuse perspective. I feel git-rebase could be better understood if nomenclature was join(slice)-commit-tree.