# How can I find all references to a submodule in my repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there any straight forward git command that I can use to get all the references of a submodule in my parent repo. Looking to find all gitlinks to a specified submodule in my parent repo.
Something like git ls-tree that enlists all references.

Comment: You mean, beside the `git submodule status --recursive` mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490756/6309?

Comment: @VonC, this would give me the SHAs for all submodules in the current branch. I'm looking to get all the references to one specific submodule. Let's say the submodule **X** is referenced in commits **a, b, c** in the parent repo. I need to get a list of all these commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say the submodule X is referenced in commits a, b, c in the parent repo. I need to get a list of all these commits.

You can for commits where X was added or deleted, using a [diff filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

```
git log --diff-filter=AD -- X
```

(note: `X`, not `X/`)

Then you can list all commits between the one where X was introduced and the one where it was deleted

```
git rev-list A ^B
```

Comment: Note: getting commits between 2 commits can be a bit tricky: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34541072/6309